# Can the default behavior of a Google Maps Event be overridden

Tags: google-maps

I am trying create a restriction on the movement of an editable polygon. I want to prevent the inside path from being pulled outside of outer path. I am using Google Maps google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation function to check if the new point is within the outer bounds but I can't find a way to stop the action from happening if it is outside.

I have tried returning false but the polygon still goes to the new location

```
google.maps.event.addListener(poly.getPaths().getArray()[1], 'set_at', function() {
  return keepInside(this, arguments[0], arguments[1]);
});

function keepInside(polygon, index, new_point)
{
    outer_edge = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: polygon.getArray(),
    });
    is_in = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(new_point,outer_edge);
    if(!is_in)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got pretty close with your original code. Instead of returning false, you could set the point back to it's original position. Also, the second argument passed to the `set_at` listener is not the new point but the old point. Try this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(poly.getPaths().getArray()[1], 'set_at', function(index, oldPoint) {
  return keepInside(this, index, this.getAt(index), oldPoint);
});

function keepInside(polygon, index, newPoint, oldPoint)
{
    outer_edge = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: polygon.getArray(),
    });
    if(!google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(newPoint, outer_edge))
    {
        polygon.setAt(index, oldPoint);
    }
}
```